# Scaling a element inside an animation with same property

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, transform

I'm trying to scale an element that's in an animation on hover. My animation consists of three elements

```
li{
  &.current-projects {
    -webkit-animation: first 5s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: first 5s infinite ease-in-out;
  }

  &.secret {
    -webkit-animation: second 5s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: second 5s infinite ease-in-out;
  }

  &.favorite {
    -webkit-animation: third 5s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: third 5s infinite ease-in-out;
  }    
  &:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(80%);
    filter: brightness(80%);
  }
}
```

in each of my animations the transform method is called.

```
@-webkit-keyframes first {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
    transform: translateX(50%);
    right: 50%;
    top: 0%;
  }

  33% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    right: 0;
    top: 100%;

  }

  66% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(100%, -100%);
    transform: translate(100%, -100%);
    top: 100%;
    right: 100%;
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
    transform: translateX(50%);
    right: 50%;
    top: 0%;
  }
}
```

My problem, is on hover I have set the images to freeze in place on hover of one of them, but I cannot get it to scale. It seems to be from having transforms in my animation (the brightness works but no scale), is there a way I can scale these using css or js and have them actually scale?
http://cdpn.io/oKpBh

Comment: Can you do this on codepen.io so that we can test it?

Answer (score 0):

I tried out something but I am not sure if this what you wanted: http://codepen.io/nighrage/pen/qywCi/

The animations on the li seem to stop the object from scaling up. So the trick  that you can do is add animations on the li and add the background to the a tag and give the link a height and width of 6em.

http://codepen.io/nighrage/pen/ExvHq/

I didnt polish up the code but I am sure that you would be able to do that.

Comment: @Snowfiring didnt manage to polish up all the minor bugs but you should be able to do that. Have a look at the new codepen